# Vuejs and Firebase : can't access to "this" inside onSnapshot()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, this

I am using vuejs and Firebase and I have a problem to acces to "this" property inside an onSnapshot callback.

This is my code :

```
import db from './firebaseInit'

export default {

    name: 'dashboard',

    data() {

        return {
            posts: [],
            connected_users: [],
            test: [],
        }
    },

    created() {

        db.collection('flutter_data').get().then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

                const data = {
                    'id': doc.id,
                    'userName': doc.data().userName,
                    'title': doc.data().title,
                    'like': doc.data().like,
                    'url': doc.data().url,
                    'type': doc.data().type,
                    'userID': doc.data().userID,
                    'userlikers': doc.data().userlikers
                };
                this.posts.push(data)
            })
        });

        db.collection('connected_users').get().then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

                const data = {
                    'userID': doc.data().userID,
                    'userName': doc.data().userName,
                    'connected': doc.data().connected
                };
                this.connected_users.push(data)
            })
        });

        db.collection('flutter_data').where("userName", "==", "Simon à tout moment")
            .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {

                snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {

                    const data = {
                        'id': change.id,
                        'userName': change.doc.data().userName,
                        'title': change.doc.data().title,
                        'like': change.doc.data().like,
                        'url': change.doc.data().url,
                        'type': change.doc.data().type,
                        'userID': change.doc.data().userID,
                        'userlikers': change.doc.data().userlikers
                    };

                    if (change.type === "added") {
                        console.log("New post: ", change.doc.data());
                    }
                    if (change.type === "modified") {
                        console.log("Modified post: ", change.doc.data());
                        console.log(this);
                    }
                    if (change.type === "removed") {
                        console.log("Removed post: ", change.doc.data());
                    }
                });
            });
    }}
```

My problem is inside this method :

```
 db.collection('flutter_data').where("userName", "==", "Simon à tout moment")
    .onSnapshot(function(snapshot)
```

I can't access to the "this" property like in this method :

```
  db.collection('flutter_data').get().then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

            const data = {
                'id': doc.id,
                'userName': doc.data().userName,
                'title': doc.data().title,
                'like': doc.data().like,
                'url': doc.data().url,
                'type': doc.data().type,
                'userID': doc.data().userID,
                'userlikers': doc.data().userlikers
            };
            this.posts.push(data)
        })
    });
```

Here, "this.posts.push(data) works, but in the onSnapshot(...) I can't do the same thing.. I want to do this in order to update my website in real time and see the changements each time a post on my Firebase is modified.

Can someone explain me why this in not accessible and maybe how can I do it differently ?

Comment: If I'm not wrong it's because you are not using arrow functions for those so you should use arrow function if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to save your `this` reference prior to pulling data, because `this` inside the Promise is no longer the Vue instance, so you could try this:

```
let vueInstance = this;
db.collection('flutter_data').get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

        const data = {
            'id': doc.id,
            'userName': doc.data().userName,
            'title': doc.data().title,
            'like': doc.data().like,
            'url': doc.data().url,
            'type': doc.data().type,
            'userID': doc.data().userID,
            'userlikers': doc.data().userlikers
        };
        vueInstance.posts.push(data)
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is working ! But I need to refresh the page in order to see the change caused by the push.. Is there a way to refresh the page at the same time ?

Comment: I have found a way : using location.reload(); but this is not very "sexy", is there a way to see the change without reloading the entiere page ?

Comment: I think this should be automatically with Vue, Do you have any error messages on the Console log? have you tried to watch the variable https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Comment: if you just print the json representation of post, do you see the changes? or maybe using the Vue Chrome developer tools to detect whether post is being populated or not

Comment: In fact, this is working but it display in real time the modified post under the original and when I refresh the original disappear

Comment: You could store the posts into an object instead of an array, or replace the entire array since you are getting all the collection...  so before `querySnapshot.forEach` empty posts array -> `vueInstance.posts=[]`

Comment: Thank you so much ! This is working (with some other conditions I've added) perfectly fine !

Comment: Sound great! happy to help